# Open RStudio Project from the attached volume when starting Rocker container

Tags: r, docker, containers, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am trying to build my works using Docker System. It would be nice to start Rstudio server when I start a container attaching a project from a mounted volume. For example, I can start the docker as,

`docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v $(pwd):/home/rstudio --name rocker rocker/verse:latest`

It runs Rstudio server and I can access it from 8787 port but it would be nice to load the project from `/home/rstudio` when I start the container.

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this? I'm looking for the same thing

Answer (score 1):

There's a hidden file you can modify:

```
~/.rstudio/projects_settings/switch-to-project
```

Populate it with the path of the project you want RStudio to open at startup.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I found it when googling the exact same problem and found a hint to the solution on an old posit post here:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-set-the-default-startup-project-in-rocker-tidyverse/63092

Here's a more complete answer than the one provided in the posit community forum:

I'm assuming you know how to build images from the dockerfile. If not then you need to learn how to build from a dockerfile first, and then come back here to see how to modify the dockerfile to do what you want.

Download the rocker dockerfile from the rocker github.

E.g., from

https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/blob/master/dockerfiles/verse_4.3.2.Dockerfile

Then edit it in your favourite text editor with the following modifications:

First you'll have to get your .Rproj project file into the container. You can do that by coping it across (you can google how to do that), but I've been cloning from my gitlab. To do so add this to the bottom of the dockerfile:

```
RUN cd /home/rstudio \
  && sudo git clone https://gitlab.com/your_git_username/your_project \
  && sudo chown -R rstudio:rstudio /home/rstudio/your_project
```

We're cd'ing into the /home/rstudio directory, and then cloning the project down into it. To do this you'll need your git project to be public-facing. I'm sure there are ways of cloning in a non-private projects, but the theory will be the same. Obviously you need to change `your_git_username` and `your_project` to whatever's pertinent.

Then add this next line to the end of the dockerfile , below the git clone step (if you used that) to set the project to open at startup:

```
RUN echo 'setHook("rstudio.sessionInit", function(newSession) { if (newSession && is.null(rstudioapi::getActiveProject())) rstudioapi::openProject("/home/rstudio/your_project/your_project.Rproj") }, action = "append")' > /home/rstudio/.Rprofile
```

Again, change `your_project` and `your_project.Rproj` to whatever's pertinent.
Then when you run the docker image, and go to localhost:8787 it should open rstudio, then refresh and open the project.

What we're doing here is echo'ing the contents of the quote marks into the `.Rprofile` file. That .Rprofile is run when rstudio starts up, and the `rstudioapi::openProject()` function is triggered by `setHook` and voilà, the specified project opens.

I've also posted something similar on the posit community forum.